# How to plot table and scatterplot side by side in plotly3 (not plotly4)

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

I have been trying to plot a table and a scatter plot side by side using plotly but to no avail for a long period. How can we do that?

## How to plot table and scatter plots in plotly3.6?

I have tried this so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.plotly as pyp
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.tools as tls
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

# subplots table
fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_xaxes=True)
trace1 = go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3])
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':list('ABC'),
                  'salary': [1000,2000,3000]})


table = ff.create_table(df)
fig.append_trace(table, 1, 2)
py.iplot(fig)
```

But this does not work.
However,
`iplot(table)` works.

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are close but forgot the specs element. Also, you must specify positioning in `.add_trace()` with `row=#` and `col=#`  Hope this helps.

```
    from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
    columns =['one','two']
    cellValues =['first piece of data', 'second piece of data']
    figure = make_subplots(
        rows = 1, cols  =2,
        specs=[[{"type":"table"},{"type" : "scatter"}]]
    )
    figure.add_trace(go.Table(header=dict(
        values = columns
        #other elements here
    ),cells=dict(
        values = cellValues
    ), row=1, col=1
    )
    figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3]),row=1,col=2)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`ff.create_table()` creates a full `Figure` not a trace, so you can't append it to a pre-existing `Figure`. You'll have to go the other way and add the `Scatter` to the output of `ff.create_table()`.